# Preventing Samsung Device care from deleting files

Tags: android, local-storage, android-sdcard, samsung-mobile

Important data required for our Android app to function properly (such as downloaded mp3 audio files and images) are often reported by users as “lost” / “got deleted” / “app ate data for lunch”. It was a mystery up until recently when we were physically able to test and verify that Samsung’s Device Care app actually deletes part of this data or at times all of it while “cleaning up and saving storage”. This is devastating as users frequently run this without realizing it’s deleting important data. How do we prevent it from doing this? Is there an option that you set in your manifest and mark a directory as important to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling Auto Optimisation. Also, avoid optmizing frequently.

Comment: That already established, but we need to be able to advertise from within the app to stop doing this.